# Pyspark comparing Dataframe column value to a variable

Tags: pyspark

I am very new to PySpark. I am trying to compare (`if` stmt) a `Dataframe` column value to a variable in Python and then take necessary action based on its result. However, I can not seem to get it right.

If "filename" column in the DF has more than 1 unique value, Or if the distinct DF "filename" value is not equal to the variable `in_file`, then "Pass", else "Fail"

```
in_file = "my_file.txt"

if df.select(df.filename).distinct().count() > 1 or df.select(df.filename).distinct().collect()[0][0] != in_file:
    print("Fail")
else:
    print("Pass")
```

What is the best/smart way to do similar comparisons between DF column and a variable in PySpark so that the program can branch based on the result of the comparison?

Comment: what is the actual intent of the comparison? do you want to do some operations on the df based on those counts? see if you can use `when().otherwise()` in that case -- if not, an optimal way to do what you're doing is to aggregate in such a way to use `collect()` only once

Comment: i just want to know how to compare the value of a DF column to a Python variable. Can this be used in a `if`-`else` statement ?

Comment: pyspark has the ability to compare a dataframe's column values (per row) against other values -- it's [`when().otherwise()`](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/)